# Unable to push items in MongoDB array using Mongoose with mlab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection named "advertisments". I have defined its schema as such:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const AdvertismentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image_or_video_link: String,
    file_type: String,
    content: String,
    published_media: [{
        media_id: String,
        title: String,
        channel_id: String
    }],
    createdOn: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const Advertisment = mongoose.model('Advertisment', AdvertismentSchema);

module.exports = Advertisment;
```

In my POST request (Node.js and Express) I want to push a new item to the published_media array. I am doing the following:

```
const advertisment = require('../models/Advertisment');
router.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    advertisment.updateOne(
        {"_id": "5d5a92ec769a993bb48a289f"},
        {
            "$push": { 
                "published_media": {
                    "media_id": "test",
                    "title": "Test",
                    "channel_id": "test"
                }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

But when I see the collection on mlab there is no published_media key in the record. Everything else works fine, I am able to connect to the db (via passport), create a new record, update a record (non push related updates). So I fail to understand why the push operation fails.

Comment: If the field is absent in the document to update, $push adds the array field with the value as its element.

If the field is not an array, the operation will fail.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#definition

Comment: So by default the published_media is not present in the existing collection records as I made that change later, but shouldn't it add it to the existing record based on the schema?